# how to check fatal error in cakephp2 in whole site

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I want to check the fatal error in the whole site if the error exists on that time I want to send the mail to site owner with a line or file name In cakephp2. is it possible?

Comment: Step 1. Go to `cakephp\app\Config` folder and open `core.php` .

Step 2. Now find `Configure::write(‘debug’, 0);` Now you can change the value to 1 or 2.  Btw fatal error will anyhow show to you as it will stops everything

Answer (score 0):

You can manage error message of your website through core.php file

Open core.php file inside app/config/core.php

You will find  `Configure::write('debug', 2);`

- **Production Mode**:
- 0: No error messages, errors, or warnings shown. Flash messages redirect.
  *
- **Development Mode**:
- 1: Errors and warnings shown, model caches refreshed, flash messages halted.
- 2: As in 1, but also with full debug messages and SQL output.
- 3: As in 2, but also with full controller dump.